# How do I get the stack trace information?

Tags: c++, networking, error-handling

I am working on a server programming on linux machine using epoll and I have a problem with debugging. Right now I have placed log statements all over the place. It helps to see when it blows up but it is hard to see why..

So I was wondering if there is a way to print a stack trace or something more information in C++.

Thanks in advance...

edit:

I set -g in mu make file and if I run my server on GDB then it won't receive any packets. I don't know why but If I run this on command line then it receives packets but if I run this on GDB it doesn't receive anything from client(I can not see any log statements)

Comment: I think you will need a debugger. Probably GDB as you are on Linux

Comment: Try running your program under [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). It has command named `bt` which does what you want.

Comment: If by "blows up" you mean crashes (like sigsegv), then you can compile the program with debug information, enable core dumps and then use gdb on the coredump. The coredump should tell you where the program crashed.

Comment: can you please share the steps you followed to start your application in gdb ?
In past I had used gdb for my application and didn't find any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [`backtrace`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) function in Glibc.

Answer (score 1):

you can run your program using `gdb` debugger.

If you are using gcc you have to recompile it with `-g` or other debugging flag.

So your exe contain more information about your program.

Comment: In my make file, I set CC:=g++ and CFLAGS:= -DDEBU1 -DCONFIG_EMBEDDED -DUSE_IND_THREAD -DFIXED. And I put this all:$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o server $(SOURCE) $(LIBS) so do I add -g after -o? Thanks in advance...

Comment: while starting gdb you can have breakpoint like . filename:lineno 
or class:functionname . 
to set use break and than your break point specifier. 
use run to start application , gdb will stop when one of the breakpoint reached. 
there you can use bt command to see bracktace.

Comment: you can also use print to watch variables. read gdb tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If your program can detect when it crashes, you can potentially write out a script and start GDB on it. That script could then get GDB to print out a backtrace.

Based on what kind of information you want, looking at `/proc/<pid>/stack` might help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **backtrace() from GLIBC** and it works excellent (backtraces can be additionally collected over network using UDP protocol):

http://blog.aplikacja.info/2010/12/backtraces-for-c/